# Parse code not executed when device disconnected from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, ibeacon

I have strange problem here. I'm testing some things with beacons.

The following code will add a row with values in the Parse DB and the device display will turn purple when the beacon is close to it.

This al works great when running from Xcode with the device connected via usb - lightning.
But when I run the app "standalone" without cable and xcode, the values aren't stored in the DB, although the device turns purple.

I'm using the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "01122334-4556-6778-899A-ABBCCDDEEFF0")!, identifier: "Estimotes")

    // Note: make sure you replace the keys here with your own beacons' Minor Values
    let colors = [
        1: UIColor(red: 84/255, green: 77/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1), // purple
        2: UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 212/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1),
        3: UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 213/255, blue: 181/255, alpha: 1),
        4: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1) //White

    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity == CLProximity.Immediate }
        if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
            let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]
            registerBeacon(closestBeacon.minor.integerValue)
        }
        else {
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[4];
        }
    }

    func registerBeacon(minor: Int) {

        let gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
        gameScore["minor"] = minor
        gameScore["beacon"] = "01"
        gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {

                // The object has been saved.
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how about doing some more debugging when the phone is disconnected to see what could be happening? maybe set a label to something if the save completes (something you can see without debugger)

Comment: I agree with the above suggestion.  In addition I would add code to write the `error.description` to the screen, perhaps in a dialog.